# Our domain is being appended onto emails addresses that are sent from our server, why?

Tags: domain-name-system, sendmail, email-bounces, email

Our app sends out many types of email notifications. On some occasions, we see that the email addresses are getting our domain appended to them.

e.g. michael@gmail.com turns into michael@gmail.com.example.com

What is causing this?

The App is running on a LAMP stack. We're using Sendmail / PEAR's Mail module.

Comment: What happens if you send out a message from Sendmail directly via bash (`sendmail -t someone@example.com`)?

Answer (score 1):

Check your mail server's configuration for the hostname! Also, often a missing dot at the end of a name in your bind configuration might cause this!

Answer (score 0):

If you do have a wildcard record for your domain (*.example.com above) it might be that a rule in mailer config is firing which appends the domain name when searching for it.

What does the output of

```
dig -t any gmail.com.example.com
```

give? anything about a valid A record or MX record?